# How to use rsync for backing up the entire filesystem – include/exclude rules file

Tags: backup, freebsd, rsync

I am trying to set up rsync backup for my FreeBSD servers.

I’ve put together an rsync-command that looks like this:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress --delete --delete-excluded \
--exclude-from=/root/rsync-excludes \
-e ssh / backup@my.backup.box:Backups/location
```

My `/root/rsync-excludes` file looks like this:

```
- *~
+ /root
+ /usr/home
+ /usr/srv
+ /etc
+ /usr/local/etc
+ /var/backups
+ /usr/local/pgsql/backups
- /root/.my.cnf
- /*
```

But for some reason, it only backs up /etc and /root, leaving out the other files. Can someone explain why?

### Solution

As per the answer from Gilles, I figured it out, and my config now looks like this:

```
- *~
+ /etc
+ /root
+ /usr/
+ /usr/home
+ /usr/local/
+ /usr/local/etc
+ /usr/local/git
+ /usr/local/pgsql/
+ /usr/local/pgsql/backups
- /usr/local/pgsql/*
+ /usr/local/varnish
- /usr/local/*
+ /usr/srv
- /usr/*
+ /var/
+ /var/backups
- /var/*
- /root/.my.cnf
- /*
```

Comment: Do you think you can restore full system using rsync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During a recursive traversal, rsync matches each directory against the rules. When it comes to `/usr`, the first matching rule is `- /*`. Therefore `/usr` is excluded, and rsync doesn't even look at anything below it. Fix: explicitly include `/usr`, as well as `/usr/local`, `/usr/local/pgsql` and `/var`.

The rsync manual has a more extended discussion under “include/exclude pattern rules” (admittedly not the easiest read).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting --one-file-system behavior.  This may be the default on freebsd.

I also see that your destination is not a root account which should break retaining permissions and ownership.

Comment: `--one-file-system` is not the default, I was rather that I had the exclusion rules wrong as Gilles suggested.

As for the destination not being root, that is true, but it’s not really an issue for my use.